# Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') to 'int'

Tags: objective-c, implicit-conversion, implicit

I'm trying to build a project to distribute this app.
But - this application, is too old from far.
So, i'm using Xcode 8.3.3 and IOS Sierra.

Instead of this i'm having the problem SistemaCardapio/SistemaCardapioAppDelegate.m:60:28: Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') to 'int'

ARC - Desactivated for all build items needed.

I've tried to work on it, doing hand to hand, but is too many items to fix.

```
int timeOutParaImpressao = 0;
timeOutParaImpressao = [preferencias integerForKey:@"timeout_impressao"];
if (timeOutParaImpressao == 0) {
    NSLog(@"sem timeout pra impressao definido");
    timeOutParaImpressao = 20;
    [preferencias setInteger:timeOutParaImpressao forKey:@"timeout_impressao"];
}
configuracoes.timeOutImpressao = timeOutParaImpressao;
```

I Would like to remove this warnings, and compile the project on Xcode.

Comment: So what's the question? Warnings don't prevent compiling the project, so what's the problem? Is it that you don't _know_ what to do or is it that you don't _want_ to do it because it is "too many items"? Or do you just want to suppress the warnings and ignore them even though they are right?

Comment: Warnings are theoretically preventing the build.
So is there any way not to prevent - the build being done by the warnings given in the question? See, I have over 1600 to fix, no laziness is that I need to kill this today.

Comment: Well an `int` is not an `integer`. So `int` was always a wrong way to declare `timeOutParaImpressao` if we're going to proceed to use `integerForKey` etc. You can fix that or not, but if you do, you're going to do it one by one. How many there are or your time frame is, that's nothing to do with us.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The warning is pretty clear: `timeOutParaImpressao` is declared as `int` which is a 32 bit integer and `integerForKey` returns a 64 bit integer on 64 bit machines.

Solution: Declare `timeOutParaImpressao` as `NSInteger`

```
NSInteger timeOutParaImpressao = 0;
```

Take warnings seriously and fix them.